# Postgresql : how to write a WHERE clause using a variable which can be a string OR a date

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I would like to write a postgreSQL script that allows to find a patient in a db according to whether one enters his name (string) or date of birth (date) in the form.

Scripts with name alone or date of birth alone works fine, but when  combined with the OR condition, it works for dates but not for strings : when you search with a name, the entry is considered invalid for the date type.

```
<form method="GET">

<p>Name or Date of Bith: <input name=saisie><br>
<input type=submit value="Find"><br>
</p>
</form>

<?php 
$c=pg_connect("dbname=dbname user=user");

if (isset($_GET["saisie"])) :
    $saisie=$_GET["saisie"];
    $reponse=pg_query($c,"SELECT patient_id,name,firstname,dob FROM patient WHERE name like '$saisie%' OR dob='$saisie' ORDER BY name");
[blablabla....]
?>
```

I am surprised because the OR condition is supposed to allow a search on one or the other of the two fields: even if a string is invalid for the field "dob" (date), it should fit for the field "name " (string) and a  search should be launched accordingly, not return a "invalid syntax for date type" error ...
Needless to say I'm a beginner in postgreSQL (or any langage, really) and I'm lost, any hint will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: You should read about [Prepared Statements in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  Note that it usually doesn't make sense to bind the same value to more than one wildcard in any case.

Comment: `$saisie ` is string or date. If it is a string and you want to cast to date like : `OR dob='$saisie':: timestamp `

Comment: How can the name and dob both yield the same result? That to me would be (an or) the issue.

Comment: btw your like statement means "begins with" $saisie. You are probably looking for "contains" that is `LIKE '%$saisie%'`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, I don't see why ? DOE John born the 2001-01-01 will be on the list either  DOE is searched for or  2001-01-01 is searched for. That's exactly what  is wanted.

Comment: @Guad You're saying that by entering "John" in the input, it will show a result for either column? That's confusing.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner. If DOE is entered shouldn't the "WHERE name like '$saisie%" get to play and if it's 2001-01-01 then " OR dob='$saisie' " should play ? That's how my beginner's brain understands OR : look in either column and see if there's a match. Does the OR condition works only on the same column ?

Comment: @LelioFaieta We always type the first letters when we search a patient by name so $saisie% seems appropriate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will.  I have used  db  where one could enter either the name or the date of birth to find patients. I just want to reproduce the same.

Comment: Someone provided you with an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection, and it will never perform well because of the `OR`.

But to get rid of the error message, you can simply cast the date to `text` before comparing:

```
... OR CAST(dob AS text) = '$saisie'
```